# AngularJS pre-bootstrap loading, gets stuck on wait infinelty

Tags: angularjs, typescript, bootstrapping

I am new here so I am going to give my best shot to describe the issue.
I am trying to achieve functionality similar to, this library [here](https://github.com/philippd/angular-deferred-bootstrap/)

I am trying to achieve same functionality but using Type script, resolving constants before angular is bootstrapped. My issue is when something goes wrong like, if app could not locate resources at the time of loading it just waits infinitely. Is there any way I can catch errors like this and more and display appropriate error message if something goes wrong?

```
mydifferedboot.bootstrap({
  element: document,
  module: appname,
  options: {strictDi: true},
  resolve: {
    before: [
      {
        module: 'actualmoduletobeload',
        resolve: {
          NEWSERVER: ($http) => {

            'ngInject';
            return $http
              .get('asset/hello.json')
              .then((result) => result.data)
              .catch((err) => {
                $('#preloader>#status')

                  // if something goes wrong
                  .css('background-image', 'none')

                  //user-friendly error message
                  .html('<p ><b>Something went wrong!</b>  Please try refreshing the page.</p><br />Unable to get <code>asset/my.json</code>.<br /><br />');
              });
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: Question: Have you tried to just use that library? All JavaScript is valid TypeScript. You can add type information later and still run the code. Given that, I don't understand why you would need a TypeScript version. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I have to built functionality of loading any constants before , at the same time or after loading particular sections in that order, that's one of the reasons to write my own library.

Comment: Not what I meant. I mean put the JS code in a TS file, compile it, ignore warnings/errors, and just use it. It will run if JS is valid so you don't need to do anything special to get TypeScript working out of the box if you have a working JS example it can be used verbatim. Just rename to `.ts` and run `tsc`

Comment: In other words take working `.js`, rename to `.ts` and then run `$ tsc --init` and then `$ tsc  --watch --project tsconfig.json --target es5`